# Struggling with exemption 'Unity.Exceptions.InvalidRegistrationException'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I installed Unity and followed this guys example to implement dependency injection into my mvc application,[Link](https://medium.com/aeturnuminc/repository-pattern-with-dependency-injection-mvc-ef-code-first-91344413ba1c) now when i run my project i am faced with the following exemptions.

System.InvalidOperationException: 'An error occurred when trying to create a controller of 
type 'SaaS.Controllers.AccountController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless
 public constructor

InvalidRegistrationException: Exception of type 
'Unity.Exceptions.InvalidRegistrationException' was thrown.

```
 [Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    private ITenantRepository TenantRepo;
    private ISetupRepository SetupRepo;
    private IAppUserRepository AppUserRepo;
    private IEmployeeRepository EmployeeRepo;

    public AccountController()
    {

    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager, ITenantRepository TenantRepo,
        ISetupRepository SetupRepo, IAppUserRepository AppUserRepo, IEmployeeRepository EmployeeRepo)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
        this.TenantRepo = TenantRepo;
        this.SetupRepo = SetupRepo;
        this.AppUserRepo = AppUserRepo;
        this.EmployeeRepo = EmployeeRepo;
    }
```

one of the repoitories

```
    public static void RegisterComponents()
        {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<ISetupRepository, SetupRepository>();
        container.RegisterType<ITenantRepository, TenantRepository>();
        container.RegisterType<ISetupLocationRepository, SetupLocationRepository>();
        container.RegisterType<ISetupCalendarOfficeRepository, SetupCalendarOfficeRepository>();
        container.RegisterType<IAppUserRepository, AppUserRepository>();
        container.RegisterType<ICacheService, InMemoryCache>();

        container.RegisterType<IEmpPersonalDetailRepository, EmpPersonalDetailRepository>();
        container.RegisterType<IEmpSportRepository, EmpSportRepository>();
        container.RegisterType<IEmployeeRepository, EmployeeRepository>();

        container.RegisterType<IEmpContactDetailRepository, EmpContactDetailRepository>();

        container.RegisterType<IEmpEmploymentDetailRepository, EmpEmploymentDetailRepository>();
        container.RegisterType<IEmpVacationEntitlementRepository, EmpVacationEntitlementRepository>();
        container.RegisterType<IEmpCalendarRepository, EmpCalendarRepository>();

        container.RegisterType<IEmpSalaryRepository, EmpSalaryRepository>();
        container.RegisterType<ISetupSalaryComponantRepository, SetupSalaryComponantRepository>();
        container.RegisterType<ISetupPayGradeRepository, SetupPayGradeRepository>();
        container.RegisterType<IEmpPartSalaryRepository, EmpPartSalaryRepository>();
        container.RegisterType(typeof(IUserStore<ApplicationUser>), typeof(UserStore<ApplicationUser>));


        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
    }

    public class SetupRepository : ISetupRepository/*, IDisposable*/
    {
    [Dependency]
    public DataBaseContext context { get; set; }

    public void Add(Setup entity)
    {
            context.Setups.Add(entity);
            context.SaveChanges();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `AccountController` constructor has parameters for `ApplicationUserManager` and `ApplicationSignInManager` and these are not registered in your container, so Unity doesn't where it's supposed to get those values from. If you register those two types (or instances), it should work for you.

Comment: container.RegisterType<IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, DataBaseContext>();
            container.RegisterType<ApplicationSignInManager>();
            container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
            container.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
            container.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>();

Comment: The same issue/problem , I think Unity and Identity are not that easily resolved. with poor documentation on how to implement this.

Comment: But is it the same container? Your `RegisterComponents` method creates a new container there. So if you are registering additional types in a different location, then you need to make sure you are using the same container object.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a class library and an Web API project.

In my implementation, I had injected the Interface from my class library to the constructor of my controller.

In this case, go to UnityConfig.cs file and add both the Interface and controller that you wish to inject.

```
    container.RegisterType<IEmailNotificationService, EmailNotificationService>();
    container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());
```

Cheers.